# Javascript - Alert() add button to close

Tags: javascript, ios

is there any chance to add button to function alert() ?

```
alert("Payment changed");
```

In iOS i have a problem if I show this alert, then it stuck on the screen and user cannot close it. I use a webView.

Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the issue? Alert boxes should have an OK button by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `confirm("Payment changed")`